# Checking the status of step function in cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-step-functions, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am writing a cloudformation template, where in I will have a lambda backed custom resource, which will trigger a step function execution.
This step function can take more than 15 minutes to execute, so I cannot wait for its completion in the invoking lambda. So the Lambda will return immediately after invoking the step function.
However I want to wait for step function to complete before proceeding with creation of another resource based on step function output.

How can this be achieved. The step function I am referencing is already created and not part of my current stack.

I know cloudformation supports wait Condition and wait condition handle, but that would require updating the step function to call wait condition handle , which is not possible, as step function is owned by a different team.

Is there any way this can be resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Tricky thing. But you can try using CloudWatch event to listen for given event configuration:

```
            EventPattern:
                source:
                    - "aws.states"
                detail-type:
                    - "Step Functions Execution Status Change"
```

Then, you can write your own Lambda function that trigger your wait condition. Or, if it's possible to exactly filter event you want to wait for, bind this event pattern target directly to SNS topic, so you won't need custom code for this if you can express your requirements in simple JSON filter.